# given $('<div><span>Foo</span></div><span>Bar</span>') write jquery to select the spans

Tags: jquery

Given `$('<div><span>Foo</span></div><span>Bar</span>')` write jquery to select the spans

Can this be expressed with just a selector?

`$('<div><span>Foo</span></div><span>Bar</span>').filter('span')` will give you the Bar span

`$('<div><span>Foo</span></div><span>Bar</span>').find('span')` will give you the Foo span

I want both.

Comment: What, why? What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @Josh, I think `find` should be used here, not `filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('<div><span>Foo</span></div><span>Bar</span>')
    .children().addBack().filter('span')
```

### update:

if you're still using a version of jQuery older then  1.8 you should use `andSelf` instead of `addBack`

Comment: `.andSelf` has been removed and replaced by [`.addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)